# Physical signification of $\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = f'(u) \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Tags: resource-recommendations, differentiation

When reading a note about finite volume method for Partial differential equations and there numerical methods, i read $\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = f'(u) \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ means that locally at each cell interface the direction of the transport is defined by the sign of $f'(u)$. what's the meaning of this.

It will be very helpful for me if you can give me some notes or references on the physical significations of other mathematical equalities

N.B : The general context : generic scalar conservation law

$ \dfrac{\delta u}{\partial u} + \dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = 0 $

$u$ is the unknown of the PDE (i.e velocity of fluid) and $f$ is the physical flux.

Comment: You should define what your variables are and give more context, as we wont know what each term is otherwise.

Comment: @Triatticus If you are familiar with fluid dynamics, then no further clarification is really needed. This is all standard notation for standard things.

Comment: @Triatticus i edited the question, i hope is it more clear now.

Comment: If the partial derivative of u with respect to x is always positive or always negative, then the sign of $f'(u)$ will determine the sign of the partial derivative of f with respect to x. To give physical significance to this you need to define what your variables physically mean.

Comment: Certainly thats what I thought considering the word transport. But my comment is more in line with the quality/context of the question than assuming variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

The definition $\partial f / \partial u = f'$ is called the Flux Jacobian. There is a set of slides that outlines what this looks like: [Euler equations in 1-D](http://math.tifrbng.res.in/~praveen/notes/acfd2013/euler_1d.pdf) as well as provides additional motivations for using it and other Jacobians that are useful in numerical methods.

The punchline is that splitting the equations this way allows some benefits and/or simplifications. It can be used to linearize the system, allowing further analysis. It can also be used to diagonalize the system, which separates the equations and makes them independent. The diagonal system is also nice for many other reasons.

The slides linked above give some examples and details of all of these things.